# Why Inkscape adds a white border while printing?

Tags: vector, inkscape

I use to print my Inkscape works to a pdf document in order to import them to a LaTeX document.

I always print them to a pdf file (my OS has this option by default < Kubuntu 14.04>) because I consider it to be faster to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> than going all the way to `Save As` and select the infinite options to get a pdf.

I just noticed that the printed files (both the pdf and the printed with a real printer and previews of both of them) have a "frame" (more like bands) in the right side and in the bottom. How can this be fixed or prevented?

## MWE:

Download the [MWE Files](https://goo.gl/SS2b8V), you will get a zip file containing the .svg (the source file ), the printed file (file printed to pdf ) and the saved file (Drawing.pdf). Compare the file "Printed.pdf" and "Drawing.pdf" and you will notice the band in the right and bottom of the page of "Printed.pdf" which won't appear in the "Drawing.pdf"

Comment: the download link doesn't work - can you fix it?

Comment: @SamuelDellicour Thank you so much man, for letting me know, I had to create a new file, now the file to download is available.